# Python OpenCV and media streaming

Tags: python, opencv, video, streaming

I have a webcam attached to one of my laptop. The camera is run by Yawcam . It streams video at 192.168.1.6:80 and http at 192.168.1.6:8888.

From another laptop , I can open the pages in my browser and see those streaming videos. 
But I wanted to capture those videos to do image processing with openCV and python. 
I tried the below code

```
import cv2.cv as cv

    cv.NamedWindow("camera", 1)
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM("http://192.168.1.6:80");
    while True:
        img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        cv.ShowImage("camera", img)
        if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
            break
    cv.DestroyWindow("camera")
```

But there is an error during running -- Type Error : an integer is required. 
The program runs if I replace IP address with 0. 
Is there any method to grab video streams with openCV?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for IP cameras is:

You just have to rewrite in Python

Most important:
use VideoCapture object and the open() method.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(void)
{
    cv::VideoCapture camera;
    camera.open("http://204.248.124.202/mjpg/video.mjpg"); 
    if (camera.isOpened()==true)
    {
        cv::namedWindow("camera");
        int key = 0;
        while (key != 27)
        {
            cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> image;        
            camera.grab();
            camera.retrieve(image);
            cv::imshow("camera",image);
            key = cv::waitKey(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand one place of your code -     camera.open("http://204.248.124.202/mjpg/video.mjpg"); 
From where did you get /mjpg/video.mjpg ?? I am also not using IP camera . My camera is connected to a laptop 192.168.1.6 and it is streaming videos at port 86. How will i approach then? I am on windows 7

Comment: @SubhenduSinhaChaudhuri as long as your laptop and the camera are on the same network you can access the livestream from your laptop using the given ips.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late for the answer but thought others might find it useful.

Try `pip install imutils`

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream

ips = ['192.168.1.6:80', '192.168.1.6:8888']
vs = [VideoStream(src=str(x)).start() for x in ips]
for i, vsi in enumerate(vs):
    frame = vsi.read()
    # Start your image processing here
```

This worked perfectly fine for me on Ubuntu 18.04 intel Pentium, hope it works for you too.